# Как исправить ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

```js
define("mw.module.article.slideshow",["mw.module.ui","mw.module.ad","mw.module.tracking","vendor.asset.hogan/hogan","vendor.asset.jquery/jquery"]
```

На моей странице сайта http://www.travel-buryatia.com/baikal/fauna-the-organic-world/ при перелистывании слайда в консоле от google developers:console выдаёт ошибку

> Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined.**

*Функция v*

```
v=function(){
  if(s){
    var i = {
      pageName: s.pageName.substring(0,s.pageName.lastIndexOf("_slideshow"))+"_slideshow_"+c
    };
    t.trackPage(i)
  }
}
```

*Функция g*

```
g = function(i) {
  m(i, c === f? 1 : c + 1)
}
```

*Функция m*

```
m = function(i,e) {
  if (i && i.preventDefault(), !u && (u =! 0, e !== c)) { 
    r.find(".selected").removeClass("selected").siblings("a[data-page='"+e+"']").first().addClass("selected");
    var t = l.filter(".current").first(),s=l.filter('[data-slide="'+e+'"]').first();
    if (t.fadeOut(function(){t.removeClass("current")}),s.fadeIn(function(){s.addClass("current"),u=!1}),1===c?r.find(".previous").css("visibility","visible"):c===f&&r.find(".next").css("visibility","visible"),1===e)r.find(".previous").css("visibility","hidden");else if(e===f){r.find(".next").css("visibility","hidden");var n=l.filter(".last-page").first();n&&0===n.find(".slide-overlay").length&&k()}c=e,b(++o),v(),y()}}
```

Вот эти три функции выдают общую ошибку. Ни как не пойму в чем дело, где эта ошибка? Кстати я новичок в этой области

Перед функциями вписана строка define

Comment: Если в этом коде как вы сообщаете нет ошибки, то почему консоль google Developer выдаёт мне ошибку со вписанными функциями (v g m) на странице моего сайта?

Comment: Код js написан в сокрощённом виде и по строкам, таким образом он занимает меньше места и загрузка происходит быстрее.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, проблема в этой части кода:

```
if(s){
  var i = {
    pageName: s.pageName.substring(0,s.pageName.lastIndexOf("_slideshow"))+"_slideshow_"+c
  };
  t.trackPage(i)
}
```

Вы проверяете, задан ли `s`, но не проверяете, есть ли в этом объекте ключ `pageName`.
Если такого ключа в объекте нет, будет возникать описанная ошибка.

Следовательно, проверять нужно следующим образом:

```
if (s && s.pageName) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: в данном случае достаточно было б `s && s.pageName`

Comment: Хм, вы правы. Возможно, не стоит так усложнять. Спасибо, обновил ответ.

Comment: @VenZell - не должна ли тогда в сообщении об ошибке фигурировать `lastIndexOf`, а не `substring`?

Comment: @Igor думаю, очередность не доходит

Comment: @VenZell -  зачем "думать"? `var obj = {}; obj.method1(obj.method2());` 
Что будет в консоли?

Comment: @Igor, у вас вложенность неверная для демонстрации. Проверьте эту строчку: `var obj = {}; obj.undefinedKey.method1(obj.method2());`

Comment: @Igor, можно и в скобках к `undefinedKey` обратиться, но результат тот же. В консоли ошибка `Cannot read property 'method1' of undefined`

Comment: @VenZell- точно, спасибо